# Insert and reoder an array according to changes made on a sub collection of the orignal array

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, sorting

I have two arrays: A and B, A contains all elements of B, A also contains some other elements.
When array B changes, array A should be updated according B, here're some rules:

1. in array A, we must keep the elements that not belong to array B and keep their order.
2. we can add new elements to array B, the new elements are added at the end of array B, and they are also added to the array A, following closely with the last element of array B in array A.
3. we can switch the position of two elements in array B, and relative elements in array A will also switch their position.
4. we can add new elements to array B and meanwhile switch positions of some elements (multiple switches), the array A should be updated according the 3 rules above.

I want to write a function taking 3 parameters: A, B, BX, and it will return the updated array A (we call it as AX).

Here're some examples. In all cases `A` and `B` are as follows.

```
     B = [b1, b2, b3]                A = [a1, a2, b1, a3, b2, b3, a4]
```

1. ```
   BX = [b3, b2, b1], then         AX = [a1, a2, b3, a3, b2, b1, a4]
   ```
2. ```
   BX = [b3, b1, b2], then         AX = [a1, a2, b3, a3, b1, b2, a4]
   ```
3. ```
   BX = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5], then AX = [a1, a2, b1, a3, b2, b3, b4, b5, a4]
   ```
4. ```
   BX = [b3, b1, b2, b4, b5], then AX = [a1, a2, b3, a3, b1, b2, b4, b5, a4]
   ```
5. ```
   BX = [b4, b3, b1, b2, b5], then AX = [a1, a2, b4, b3, a3, b1, b2, b5, a4]
   ```
6. ```
   BX = [b4, b3, b1, b5, b2], then AX = [a1, a2, b4, b3, a3, b1, b5, b2, a4]
   ```

How can this be done?

Comment: `I want to write a function` what's stopping you?

Comment: What's the logic of where new elements are inserted ... (i.e. b4, b5 in your examples) ... seems arbitrary

Comment: Please explain #5 in detail (by editing your question). It's not a typo because I similarly don't understand #6. I expected #5 to be `[a1, a2, b4, a3, b3, b1, b2, b5, a4].`

Comment: *"How can this be done?"*: just as you describe: I guess you know how to find an element in an array, how to replace an element in an array, how to insert an element in an array, and with those operations you can do what you describe. What is the problem?